# How can I test that two Joda-Time DateTime objects are nearly equal?

Tags: java, unit-testing

In unit tests I often have methods that return a `DateTime` on or about `now()`.  Is there a way to say that the `actual` DateTime is within a few seconds of the `actual` DateTime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, this is pretty easy with Joda Time:

```
Duration dur = new Duration(sender.getStartTime(), new DateTime());
assertTrue(5000 > dur.getMillis());
```

Answer (score 6):

That sounds like a bad idea. Unit tests should not depend in any way on the real current time... this is why it's a good practice to inject some interface, called `Clock` perhaps, in your class's  constructors and use that as the source for the current time. Then in your unit tests you can use a special implementation of that for which you can control the time it returns, making your tests deterministic.

That said, I'm sure you could easily write a method that checks that a `DateTime` is within a certain range of another `DateTime` by creating new `DateTime`s by adding and subtracting the desired number of seconds and then comparing.